# How to make a simple google map page show in IntelXDK

Tags: javascript, html, intel-xdk

I am trying to make a simple page where a google map is displayed, centered on the current location.

I have been able to sucessfully get the lat/long with the following, from where I also store it in localStorage. :

```
var geooptions = {timeout: 10000, maximumAge: 11000, enableHighAccuracy: true };
var geofail = function(){
  alert("Geolocation failed. \nPlease enable GPS in Settings.");
};
var geosuc = function(p){
  localStorage.lat = p.coords.latitude;
  localStorage.lon = p.coords.longitude; 
  localStorage.latlon = p.coords.latitude + ', ' + p.coords.longitude;    
};
var getLocation = intel.xdk.geolocation.watchPosition(geosuc,geofail,geooptions);
var stopGeolocation = function(){
        intel.xdk.geolocation.clearWatch(geolocationWatchTimer);
}
```

When I try to draw the map with this, nothing happens - I have a div with id="page_4":

```
function drawMap() {
    //Creates a new google maps object
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(localStorage.lat, localStorage.lon);
    myLatLng = latlng;
    var mapOptions = {
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
        },
    };
    var mymap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("page_4"), mapOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found issue, wasn't clear / obvious in any of the XDK examples, but you obviously still have to include the google map api script...

Comment: Monty, I know this is an old post, but I'm running into a similar issue. I tried with both Google Map API scripts (with API_Key, and without it), but I can't this thing to work. I wonder if you have any tips for me. I also wonder if the phone I'm using for testing is not letting me use localstorage. Thansk!

Comment: I did get it to work, but it broke "all by itself" again - this time, I think Google changed the way how the JS API is called or something. It looks like your API key needs to be linked to a URL/IP or App Hash ID, and I'm also now stumped as to what that should/could be for a hybrid app.